# Get width and height of an image before uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

I have been trying this code:

```
$file_tmp = $_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);
```

But it gives me an error. I'm not able to fix it

**UPDATED**

Here you have the PHP code that I have developed. How can I fix it. I have been searching for solutions in different forums...

I get this error

> Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in C:\wamp\www\tapeHD\include\php\database.php on line 282

```
    public static function SubirVideo($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $user, $descripcion){
        //ID AUTO INCREMENT
        $sql = "INSERT INTO video(nombre, directorio, imagen, visitas, likes, usuario_id, fecha_subida, descripcion) VALUES ($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, 0, 0, $user, NOW(), $descripcion)";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function SubirVideoErrores(){
        $error = "";

        if(isset($_POST["boton_upload_video"])){
            $uploadImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['name'];
            $tipoImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['type'];

            $uploadVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
            $tipoVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['type'];

            $titulo = $_POST["video_title"];
            $descripcion = $_POST["video_description"];

            $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tapeHD/include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos";

            if($tipoImagen == "image/jpeg"){
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'];
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

                if($_FILES['video_imagen']['size'] < (1024000)){
                    if($width != 320 && $height != 180){
                        $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe de ser 320x180</div></div></div>";
                    } else {
                        if($tipoVideo == "video/mp4"){
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadVideo);
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadImagen);
                            $video_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos/".$uploadVideo;
                            $imagen_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos/".$uploadImagen;
                            DataBase::SubirVideo($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $_SESSION["usuario"], $descripcion);
                            $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Tu video ha sido subido</div></div></div>";
                        } else {
                            $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El video debe estar en formato .mp4</div></div></div>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen pesa demasiado</div></div></div>";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe ser .jpg </div></div></div>";
            }
        }
        return $error;  
    }
```

HTML

```
            <div class="upload_video_fields">
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="video_form left">
                            <input type="text" id="video_title" name="video_title" placeholder="Título del video..." required />
                            <textarea id="video_description" name="video_description" placeholder="Descripción del video..." cols="40" rows="6" aria-required="true" required></textarea>

                        </div>

                        <div class="video_form right">
                            <input type="file" id="video_imagen" name="video_imagen" required />

                            <input type="file" id="video_file" name="video_file" required />
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="boton_upload_video" name="boton_upload_video" class="btn" value="Subir" />
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="upload_progress"><div class="bar"></div></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: no, that is not possible. The file is firstly accessed through the $_FILES global and secondly it would be available after upload. Once the file is uploaded it is straightforward to return the sizes but not before afaik!

Comment: So, how can I check if the image's dimensions are 320x180?

Comment: Exactly where are you thinking you want to put the size check?

Comment: After submission/upload you can check and if you want you could resize it to those dimensions

Comment: **Hang on**. Are you trying to use the `$_FILES` array in a script that was not used to do the actual UPLOAD? `database.php` looks like an odd script filename to be doing the actual uploading process????

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @RamRaider Well thanks for stating the blatently obvious. And to the upvoter... wow, what was the point of that.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to see the HTML that is used to cause this flle upload, including the `<form>` tag

Comment: This is class method! You diligently create `$error = '...'` but you never **return** that variable to the calling script. **Start by returning `$error` OR echoing `$error` then maybe you will see what is wrong with this script**

Comment: Im doing it... print $error

Comment: I have changing it, but nothing changes. It keeps giving me error. I really dont know what to do. I have another function, the same, for uploading only one image, the profile picture. I really dont know what happens... I need help real fast... RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly - steady tiger - who rattled your cage? Seemed like a reasonable comment

Comment: Ok you have changed the code to print `$error` So what do you see from these prints

Comment: Technically I guess he did not, but there is a requirement to check that the image is of a particular dimension, namely 320 x 180, which lead me to assume that the size mentioned was of relevance. Get out of bed on the wrong side this morning by any chance?

Comment: I just need to upload an image and a video. The image must be 320x180. Or I could eve resize it, but i dont know how. It would be more difficult...

Comment: Does that mean you are happy to resize it to those dimensions if the image is not already that size? Or should it be rejected?

Comment: I dont really care. It depends... if it doesnt not get distorted

Comment: I have tested a slightly modified version of this and everything seemed ok - there were no errors relating to getimagesize(). Weird as it might sound, are there references to `getimagesize()` in the `SubirVideo` method from your `Database` class? The error message points to that particular file, the `SubirVideoErrores` worked fine when I used an mp4 and a jpg of the correct size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple file uploads the following is from the manual - just in case you haven't found it. I hope that this provides sufficient guidance when trying to access the variables after upload.

```
-----------------------------------
Example #1 Uploading multiple files
-----------------------------------
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

When the above form is submitted, the arrays `$_FILES['userfile']`, `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`, and `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` will be initialized.Each of these will be a **numerically indexed** array of the appropriate values for the submitted files.

For instance, assume that the filenames `/home/test/review.html` and `/home/test/xwp.out` are submitted. In this case, `$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]` would contain the value `review.html`, and `$_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]` would contain the value `xwp.out`.

Similarly, `$_FILES['userfile']['size'][0]` would contain `review.html`'s file size, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks too much, that what I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

The sql in the `Subirvideo` function looks incorrect as none of the values have quotes around them. Technically there is no need for the quotes around the integer values but can do no harm. I added in the exit statement to the sql so that you can check the result though you say it is fine now. The main method `SubirVideoErrores` has some additional code to resize the uploaded image to the specified max dimensions ( whilst hopefully mantaining the aspect ratio )

```
public static function SubirVideo( $titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $user, $descripcion ){
    /* note: 
       Ensure that $titulo and $descripcion are properly escaped to avoid issues with quote marks etc
    */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `video` ( `nombre`, `directorio`, `imagen`, `visitas`, `likes`, `usuario_id`, `fecha_subida`, `descripcion` )
            VALUES
            ( '$titulo', '$video_directorio', '$imagen_directorio', '0', '0', '$user', now(), '$descripcion' )";

    /* Remove if the exit( sql ) if it looks correct */
    exit( $sql );
    $resultado = self::Conexion( $sql );
    return $resultado;
}

public static function SubirVideoErrores( $force_resize=true ){
    /* set the default value of $force_resize to false if you do not wish resizing by default */
    try{
        $error = "";

        $max_width=320;
        $max_height=180;

        /* I added this so I could set a var rather than use a session for testing, ie: $session_usuario='antonio' etc */
        $session_usuario=$_SESSION["usuario"];

        if( isset( $_POST["boton_upload_video"] ) ){

            $titulo = $_POST["video_title"];
            $descripcion = $_POST["video_description"];

            $uploadImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['name'];
            $tipoImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['type'];
            $uploadVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
            $tipoVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['type'];

            /* Check for errors */
            $video_upload_error = intval( $_FILES['video_file']['error'] );
            $image_upload_error = intval( $_FILES['video_imagen']['error'] );

            if( $video_upload_error > 0 or $image_upload_error > 0 ){
                exit('There were errors during the upload process');    
            }

            if( !empty( $uploadVideo ) && !empty( $uploadImagen ) ){

               $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tapeHD/include/database/usuarios/".$session_usuario."/videos";
               #$directorio = 'c:/temp/uploads_testing';

                if( $tipoImagen !== "image/jpeg"){
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe ser de formato .jpg</div></div></div>";
                    print $error;

                } else {

                    list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $_FILES["video_imagen"]["tmp_name"] );

                    if( $force_resize==true ){
                        /* Resize supplied mage to a maximum of 320x180 if it is larger then these sizes */
                        if( $width > $max_width or $height > $max_height ) {
                            if( $width > $height ){
                                /* landscape */
                                $aspect = $max_width / $width;
                                $new_width = $max_width;
                                $new_height = $height * $aspect;
                            } elseif( $width == $height ){
                                /* square */
                                $new_width=$max_height;
                                $new_height=$max_height;
                            } else {
                                /* portrait */
                                $aspect = $max_height / $height;
                                $new_width = $width * $aspect;
                                $new_height = $max_height;  
                            }

                            $uploadedimgpath=$directorio."/".$uploadImagen;

                            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadVideo );
                            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'], $uploadedimgpath );                        

                            $image = @imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
                            $background_color = @imagecolorallocate( $image, 255, 255, 255 );
                            $source = @imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploadedimgpath );

                            @imagecopyresampled( $image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height ); 
                            @imagejpeg( $image, $uploadedimgpath, 100 ); 
                            @imagedestroy( $image ); 
                            @imagedestroy( $source );

                            $width=$new_width;
                            $height=$new_height;
                        }
                    } else {
                            $uploadedimgpath=$directorio."/".$uploadImagen;

                            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadVideo );
                            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'], $uploadedimgpath );
                    }

                    if( $_FILES['video_imagen']['size'] > 1024000 ){
                        $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen pesa demasiado</div></div></div>";
                        print $error;

                    } else {

                        if( $width == 320 or $height == 180 ){
                            if( $tipoVideo == "video/mp4" ){

                                $video_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$session_usuario."/videos/".$uploadVideo;
                                $imagen_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$session_usuario."/videos/".$uploadImagen;

                                DataBase::SubirVideo( $titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $session_usuario, $descripcion );

                                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Tu video ha sido subido</div></div></div>";
                                print $error;
                            } else {
                                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El video debe estar en formato .mp4</div></div></div>";
                                print $error;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe de ser 320x180</div></div></div>";
                            print $error;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );   
    }
}
```

I have tested this and the image and video both get uploaded fine on my system ( with some path changes of course ) and both are readable. I can watch the uploaed video and view the uploaded image - even those that get resized. Is the video you upload very large?

Comment: OK, it worked perfectly @RamRaider. It inserts me the different values in my database. The problem is that the files I move, get damage. I dont know why. I can't watch the video, I can't even see the video's picture. What could it be?

Comment: Its size is 54MB @RamRaider. I have Windows 10 by the way, I dont know if that could be the problem

Comment: You have made sure that `upload_max_filesize` is set to a large enough value and that `max_execution_time` is also set large enough? Certainly 54Mb does not seem excessive but you must ensure the post can handle file more than the default 2Mb

Comment: `max_execution_time = 120` AND `upload_max_filesize = 100M` @RamRaider

Comment: or use the php command: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize',pow( 1024, 100 ) );` etc ~ that would, I think, set a 100Mb limit. Similarly for the time limit, `ini_set('max_execution_time',180);` and `ini_set('max_input_time',180);` etc

Comment: I still having this error `Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!` It must be the size. Maybe, I just can't upload video' size + image' size. I have done what you told me. I added that code to the top of my html file. But nothing happens... I really don't know what to do

Comment: The location that the tmp file gets written to during upload, does that have read permissions? check the permissions

Comment: OK, the problem was the inputs. I dont know why, but with two inpunts, my files' size was 0 bytes. I have done this... `<input type="file" id="video_imagen" name="video_file[]" multiple="multiple" required />`

Comment: As I said before, the problem was the inputsm how could I do the code I posted with Arrays?